# Pandas concat and OHLC issue

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, resampling

I have an old script and it used to work perfectly, it was designed to take tick (bid and ask) data and turn it into OHLC data using pandas `.resample` and `.agg`, like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(MDB.CHART.find()))
DF = df[['dt','bid','ask']]
DF = DF.set_index('dt')

DB = DF['bid'].resample('2T').agg({ 'openbid' : 'first',
                                    'highbid' : 'max',
                                    'lowbid'  : 'min',
                                    'closebid': 'last'})

DA = DF['ask'].resample('2T').agg({ 'openask' : 'first',
                                    'highask' : 'max',
                                    'lowask'  : 'min',
                                    'closeask': 'last'})

dg = pd.concat([DB, DA], axis = 1)

And it would produce the following DataFrame layout:

dt  openbid  highbid  lowbid  closebid  openask  highask lowask closeask
....
....
```

But now when I run the same script (with exactly the same data), I get the following:

```
                                  bid      ask
         dt                                   
closeask 2015-08-19 06:00:00      NaN  1.10619
         2015-08-19 06:02:00      NaN  1.10636
         2015-08-19 06:04:00      NaN  1.10646
         2015-08-19 06:06:00      NaN  1.10657
         2015-08-19 06:08:00      NaN  1.10649
...                               ...      ...
openbid  2015-08-20 13:28:00  1.11661      NaN
         2015-08-20 13:30:00  1.11683      NaN
         2015-08-20 13:32:00  1.11684      NaN
         2015-08-20 13:34:00  1.11697      NaN
         2015-08-20 13:36:00  1.11673      NaN

[7592 rows x 2 columns]
```

I gather, or assume that pandas has changed (again) the `resample` and the `agg` functions? Can someone do a swish of their wand and save me the trouble of putting my head near the docs?

Thanks.

ps. when I use the following

```
df = (DF.resample('2T').agg({'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'}))
I am getting a future warning:

FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
```

But as yet nothing in the docs!

Comment: Are DB and DA multiIndex? Also dictionary usage with `agg` is going to  be removed in future versions, so you should create a virtual env and retain the same python version for your code

Comment: @djk47463 cheers for the reply, I know it's going out in the new version, which is a shame as I am usig it with real time charting and the overhead will now be huge as I will have to create a new DataFrame from the individual columns. Dont worry about the question, I a in the process of carving out something that will last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from now on we'll have to use the following when using bid and ask data, as renaming with a dict is to be depreciated soon:

```
    db = DF.bid.resample('2T').ohlc().add_suffix('bid')
    da = DF.ask.resample('2T').ohlc().add_suffix('ask')
    df = pd.concat([db, da], axis = 1)

df.head(3)

                     openbid  highbid   lowbid  closebid  openask  highask   lowask  closeask
dt                                                                                           
2015-08-19 06:00:00  1.10586  1.10620  1.10558   1.10615  1.10587  1.10623  1.10560   1.10619
2015-08-19 06:02:00  1.10615  1.10650  1.10611   1.10634  1.10618  1.10652  1.10614   1.10636
2015-08-19 06:04:00  1.10634  1.10674  1.10623   1.10645  1.10637  1.10676  1.10624   1.10646
```

Comment: using https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html rather than rename for your case

Comment: As @Wen suggested use `add_suffix` instead  `DF.bid.resample('2T').ohlc().add_suffix('bid')` same thing for `ask`